# How to use join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner with SQL query, I can't quite understand how join works

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    CAST (t_Users.UserID AS INT) AS UserID,
    t_Users.FirstName, 
    t_Users.LastName, 
    t_Users.Email,
    t_Users_In_Project.ProjectID,
    t_Teachers.TeacherID,
    t_Teachers.FirstName + ' ' + t_Teachers.LastName AS TeacherName,
    t_Teachers.Email AS TeacherEmail
FROM t_Users
LEFT JOIN t_Users_In_Project
ON t_Users_In_Project.UserID = t_Users.UserID
INNER JOIN t_Projects
ON t_Projects.ProjectID = t_Users_In_Project.ProjectID
LEFT JOIN t_Teachers
ON t_Teachers.TeacherID = t_Projects.TeacherID
WHERE t_Users_In_Project.ProjectID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t_Users.UserID ASC
```

And I got this results

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| UserID | FirstName | LastName |    Email    | ProjectID | TeacherID | TeacherName | TeacherEmail |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|    284 | Person    | A        | personA.com |      1951 |        94 | Teacher A   | teacherA.com |
|    284 | Person    | A        | personA.com |       245 |        68 | Teacher B   | teacherB.com |
|    284 | Person    | A        | personA.com |       139 |        41 | Teacher C   | teacherC.com |
|    284 | Person    | A        | personA.com |       176 |        41 | Teacher C   | teacherC.com |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Meanwhile what I want is something like

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| UserID | FirstName | LastName |    Email    | ProjectID | TeacherID | TeacherName | TeacherEmail |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|    284 | Person    | A        | personA.com |      1951 |        94 | Teacher A   | teacherA.com |
|    284 | Person    | A        | personA.com |       245 |        68 | Teacher B   | teacherB.com |
|    284 | Person    | A        | personA.com |       176 |        41 | Teacher C   | teacherC.com |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Basically, I want to get user with distinct Teacher instead of distinct Project.
How can I retrieve that with SQL?

The database structure is something like

```
User
     UserID, FirstName, LastName Email
Users_in_project
     UserID, ProjectID
Project 
     ProjectID, TeacherID
Teacher
     TeacherID, FirstName, LastName, Email
```

Thanks

Comment: Which ProjectID per teacher?Or other columns which might not be the same per teacher?

Comment: Do you really need the ProjectID ?

Comment: Why does ProjectID 176 get put in the output and not projectid 136. Like... Why did YOU choose that one over the other one to display?

Comment: I add the database structure to be more clear.
@OfirWinegarten, I dont really need it, but project is the only thing that can link the data together i think

Comment: @ariestikto Then use to do your join, and don't include it in your `SELECT` clause. A `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` will then give you the results you want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using MSSQL

Comment: @JNevill no special reason, I just want to get 1 of them, I don't really care which one

Comment: @JNevill could you elaborate? I want to get all user with any combination of teachers, shouldn't I use join then?

Comment: Yes. Use a join and join on that `projectid` if that is the correct field on which to join, but don't put `projectid` up in your `SELECT` clause. Only select on the fields that you need in your output. Then for each field in your `SELECT` clause (that is being outputted) add it also to a `GROUP BY` clause so that it will be grouped and you won't get multiple records for distinct output records.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks, I use `GROUP BY` and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it to use `max()` and `group by` like this

```
select cast(t_Users.UserID as int) as UserID, t_Users.FirstName,
       t_Users.LastName, t_Users.Email, max(t_Users_In_Project.ProjectID) projectid,
       t_Teachers.AffiliateID,
       t_Teachers.FirstName + ' ' + t_Teachers.LastName as TeacherName,
       t_Teachers.Email as TeacherEmail
  from t_Users
  left join t_Users_In_Project on t_Users_In_Project.UserID = t_Users.UserID
 inner join t_Projects on t_Projects.ProjectID = t_Users_In_Project.ProjectID
  left join t_Teachers on t_Teachers.TeacherID = t_Projects.TeacherID
 where t_Users_In_Project.ProjectID is not null
 group by t_Users.UserID, t_Users.FirstName, t_Users.LastName, t_Users.Email,
          t_Teachers.AffiliateID, t_Teachers.FirstName, t_Teachers.LastName,
          t_Teachers.Email
 order by t_Users.UserID asc
```